# How not to fire observer in controller when model is set in setupController?

Tags: ember.js

I set an observer function for a model's attribute in a controller.
and It fires as soon as I enter the route for that controller.

And I know it's because of `controller.set('model', model);` in `setupController`. How can I prevent this?

I want to use observer to make another attribute changed when an attribute is changed.

But because of this behavior my logic leads to a bug.....

Route

```
MuteAdmin.NewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord(this.get('articleModelClassName'));
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);

    this.store.find(this.get('categoryModelClassName')).then(function(categories) {
      controller.set('categories', categories);

      if (model.get('category') == null) {
        model.set('category', categories.get('firstObject'));
      };
    }.bind(this));
  },

  deactivate: function() {
    if(this.controller.get('isDirty')) this.controller.get('model').deleteRecord();
  }
});
```

Controller

```
MuteAdmin.NewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(MuteAdmin.Modelable, {
  publicChanged: function() {
    console.log('How can I prevent this from printing when entering its route?');
  }.observes('public'),

  actions: {
    submit: function() {
      var currentUser = this.get('currentUser');
      var article = this.get('model');

      article.set('author', currentUser); 

      article.save().then(function() {
        this.set("flashSuccess", "Successfully Created.");

        this.transitionToRoute('index');
      }.bind(this), function() {

      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That's how properties/observers on the controller work, if the model changes, all of the properties being watched are invalidated.  The logic may need to be pushed up one level to your model.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the Ember way, but when I needed to manipulate model and controller on setup I used a flag to indicate controller is setting up.

Something like this:

```
MyRoute = ProtectedRoute.extend({
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        controller['settingController'] = true;
        controller.setProperties({
            'prop1Name' : val1,
            'prop2Name': val2,
            'propNName': valN
        });
        controller['settingController'] = false;
        // Call _super for default behavior
        this._super(controller, model);
    }
});

MyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    anAfterChangeObserver: function() {
        if(controller['settingController']){
            return;
        }
        doSomethings();
    }.observes('prop1Name')
});
```